# Flush iOS instruction cache

Tags: ios

How do you flush the instruction cache on iOS? If this is impossible on a non-jailbroken iPhone, how would you do it on a jailbroken iPhone?

Comment: I'm fairly sure the mProtect system call should flush the cache, if not, use cacheFlush().

Comment: Isn't cacheflush for Linux only? mprotect isn't, but I wonder how that would impact performance if I call it just to flush the cache.

Comment: mProtect is on iOS, however it may be in a private header (I know Apple loves guarding the memory allocation classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the cache flush functions are in libkern/OSCacheControl
Further documentation can be found here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sys_dcache_flush.3.html