# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Assembly Code in iOS App

Tags: ios, c, xcode, assembly, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to debug an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash in an iOS App I am working on. Basically, my code calls the function new_dyna_start() which corresponds to the a certain assembly method. Here's the relevant assembly code:

```
.align  4
42430:
.long _translation_cache_iphone

.align  2
.globl  _new_dyna_start
//  .type   new_dyna_start, %function
_new_dyna_start:
ldr r12, .dlptr
mov r0, #0xa4000000
stmia   r12, {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, fp, lr}
sub fp, r12, #28
add r0, r0, #0x40
bl  _new_recompile_block
ldr r0, [fp, #64]
ldr r10, [fp, #400+36] /* Count */
str r0, [fp, #72]
sub r10, r10, r0
ldr r0, 42430b
ldr pc, [r0]
```

From my (limited) understanding, at line 6 of the method, it calls the C function new_recompile_block(). This method works fine, and I know it finishes because at the end of the function I have

```
printf("End of loop");
```

which then appears in the debugger. After the method completes, I'm not entirely sure I understand what happens, but it seems that the assembly method obtains a reference to the C variable translation_cache_iphone. However, at the final line the app crashes oddly. This message appears in Xcode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/moAzS.jpg

However, if I click on the side to the last method called, I see it is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIVhU.jpg

This seems to support my idea that it is the translation_cache_iphone variable causing the crash, as the memory address of the EXC_BAD_ACCESS (0x401000) is the same as translation_cache_iphone. translation_cache_iphone is declared as:

```
unsigned char* translation_cache_iphone = NULL;
```

and is initialized by:

```
translation_cache_iphone = (unsigned char *)(((unsigned long) translation_cache_static_iphone + (4096)) & ~(4095));
```

Am I right in assuming that this is the problem? Is the problem in the assembly code, or in the C code? I've tried modifying both, but to no avail. The assembly code above is the original.

[Here is a link](https://github.com/iSkythe/N64iOS) to the full source on Github. Simply compile and run on an iDevice with Xcode and you'll see the exact issues I'm facing. It may be easier to debug that way.

Comment: What is at translation_cache_iphone? Is this some area you are allocating, filling in with code, and jumping to? If so, there are a number of issues with executing dynamically written code. The memory containing the code has to be marked executable, and instruction cache must be flushed (and other processor synchronization instructions may be necessary). Also, if you want to publish the application in the App Store, it may run afoul of the prohibition on executing interpreted code. It is very rare that an application needs to do this. What is the actual goal you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Per the [assembler reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/Assembler/020-Assembly_Language_Syntax/asm_syntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000821-TPXREF105), numeric labels can only be single digits. I would not expect `42430b` to work. This appears not to be your immediate problem, and the assembler may be accepting it, but you would be better off changing `42430` and `42430b` to a name, like `MyPointer`.

Comment: To make memory executable, see the `mprotect` system call. To invalidate instruction cache, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818928/flush-ios-instruction-cache). You should avoid using these in an application unless there is no alternative.

Comment: translation_cache_iphone is just an external reference to an unsigned char * located in the C code. I'm not trying to publish in the App Store, this will be released as an open source project for developers on Github. I'm actually not sure what it does with translation_cache_iphone, as it's not my original code.

Comment: I renamed the label to TranslationCache, and the program runs exactly the same. As for mprotect, I tried this after initializing the variable: mprotect(translation_cache_iphone, sizeof(translation_cache_iphone), PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ); but the program didn't change with this either; same exact crash. I'm running out of ideas. I've edited my question with a link to the source, so maybe it'll be easier to debug with all the code in place.

Answer (score 1):

The last two instructions form an indirect jump to the `translation_cache_iphone` which is thus expected to be executable code. Verify that is the case and that memory permissions are appropriate - in many systems data pages are not executable by default.

Comment: How can I verify this and check memory permissions? The declaration of the variable is rather simple: unsigned char* translation_cache_iphone = NULL;

Answer (score 1):

> This seems to support my idea that it is the translation_cache_iphone variable causing the crash

Yes, I believe that this variable is the problem.

In the assembly code you posted I can see one line that could cause an invalid access to the memory, and it is:

```
ldr r0, 42430b
ldr pc, [r0]
```

The first line loads the data from the label 42430 to the register r0. Then, the second line points PC (Program Counter) to the content of r0.

In the beginning of the assembly code you have declared what is the label 42430:

```
42430:
  .long _translation_cache_iphone
```

Then, when it tries to access this value and execute is as code, it crashes.

Comment: What would be the best way to go about this? I assumed the declaration of 42430 was essential. Should I declare it as something else?

Comment: `ldr r0, 42430b` does not load 42430 to r0, and the directive `.long _translation_cache_iphone` is not at location 42430. `42430:` is a label, and `ldr r0, 42430b` is an attempt to load the data at that label. However, numeric labels are supposed to be single digits; I do not know what the assembler will do in this case. Additionally, I am not sure that loading from a location is supported in this way (due to relocatability issues) or that the data defined with `.long _translation_cache_iphone` will be filled in correctly (again due to relocatability issues).

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, you are right. That is what I meant but I wrote that in a confusing way.
I will correct my answer.